# issue with a simple react native class

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am a bit new to react-native and now I am really stuck with React Natives class components

I am building a walkthrough screen using react-native-app-intro-slider

Everything works well until I click my Start buton

see the error I get when I click my button

ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation')

I am really stuck and need your help

see my code below

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, StatusBar, Image, SafeAreaView, Text, Button} from 'react-native';
import AppIntroSlider from 'react-native-app-intro-slider';

import styles from './styles';
type Item = typeof slides[0];

const onGetStartedPressed = () => {
  const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
  () => navigate('Sgnin');
};
const slides = [
  {
    key: 'one',
    title: 'item 1',
    image: Images.surb1,
    bg: '#59b2ab',
  },
  {
    key: 'two',
    title: 'item 2',
    image: Images.surb2,
    bg: '#febe29',
  },
  {
    key: 'three',
    title: 'item 3',
    image: Images.surb3,
    bg: '#22bcb5',
  },
  {
    key: 'four',
    title: 'item 4',
    image: Images.surb4,
    bg: '#0b76a2',
  },
];
export default class Start extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  _renderItem = ({item}: {item: Item}) => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: item.bg,
        }}>
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.slide}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
          <Image source={item.image} style={styles.image} />
        </SafeAreaView>
      </View>
    );
  };

  _keyExtractor = (item: Item) => item.title;
  _renderDoneButton = () => {
    return (
      <Button
        full
        style={{marginTop: 20}}
        onPress={() => onGetStartedPressed()}>
        Get Started
      </Button>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <StatusBar translucent backgroundColor="transparent" />
        <AppIntroSlider
          keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
          renderDoneButton={this._renderDoneButton}
          bottomButton
          showSkipButton
          data={slides}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is outside the class, so for that function `props` is not defined. You need to put the function inside the class.

```
export default class Start extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  onGetStartedPressed = () => {
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    navigate('Sgnin');
  };
```

and replace this:
`onPress={() => onGetStartedPressed()}`

with this:
`onPress={() => this.onGetStartedPressed()}`

Comment: const keyword does not work within a class

Comment: when the method is taken out of the class, then the error ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation')
I am exhausted

Comment: If i put the method in the class and take out the word const like said by the last entry i get
 ERROR  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: onGetStartedPressed

Comment: @MIikeEps check the edit. And I haven't used const keyword inside class.

Comment: @Tayab, you edit results in the error  ERROR  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: onGetStartedPressed

Comment: @MIikeEps try removing this from function call.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the props in **onGetStartedPressed** method

```
<Button
        full
        style={{marginTop: 20}}
        onPress={() => onGetStartedPressed(this.props)}>
        Get Started
</Button>
```

And edit the **onGetStartedPressed** method

```
const onGetStartedPressed = (props) => {
  props.navigation.navigate('Sgnin');
};
```

Comment: const keyword does not work within a class
That's the error I get after implementing your. suggestion

Comment: Yes, you can't create a const inside a class, but like you code above you can create outside of class, so if you gonna create the method inside class don't using const keyword, just like create a method.